# Shell awk command with FS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have created a script with an awk command that reads:

```
myVar=$(awk -v FS="HAMMER=" 'NF>1{print $2}' TEST.properties)
echo "Appliances="$myVar
```

The file `TEST.properties` contains the following:

```
...
HAMMER=foo1,foo2
JACKHAMMER=foo3
...
```

the above command returns

```
foo1,foo2
foo3
```

How should I modify the command to find only `HAMMER` and not every word containing `HAMMER`?

Comment: Don't use hacks like setting the search string as a field separator, use FS as a field separator. Try `awk -vFS="=" '$1=="HAMMER"{print $2}' file`

Comment: Is it always key=value ? and `HAMMER` occur in key?

Comment: Yes key=value. Hammer is key. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: If the file is harmless, what about sourcing it and printing the variable? `(source file; echo "$HAMMER" )`

Comment: when I replace '$1=="HAMMER" with '$1=="$SomeVar"  I am getting nothing back. I know the variable has a value

Answer (score 1):

Use a start of the line `^` in your field separator `FS`:

```
awk -v FS="^HAMMER=" 'NF>1{print $2}'
```

But if you have key=value construction, you'd better use:

```
awk -v FS='[=,]' '$1=="HAMMER"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++} print $i}'
```

The field separator is set to either `=` or `,`. If the first parameter is your keyword, print all other parameters of that line.

Comment: When i replace HAMMER with a variable, I do not get the variable value in the command. Ex. awk -v FS='[=,]' '$1=="${SOMEVAR}"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'

Comment: That's the consequence of the single quoted awk script. You can add another option `-v var="$SOMEVAR"` and change the script to `$1==var {...}`

Comment: like this? awk -v var="$SOMEVAR" FS='[=,]' '$1==var{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'

Comment: Like this: `awk -v var="$SOMEVAR" -v FS='[=,]' '$1==var{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'`

Answer (score 0):

either :

```
awk -F'=' '$1=="HAMMER"{print $2}' file
```

or:

```
grep -oP '(?<=^HAMMER=).*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F= '/^HAMMER=/ { print $2 }' file
```